# How to apply a background color to only half of the text on selecting?

Tags: html, css

When I select text, the background color changes to yellow.

```
body p::selection {
  background: #fcf113;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
}

body p::-moz-selection {
  background: #fcf113;
}
```

[image]

But, I want it to appear like this.

[image]

Is it possible or not?

Comment: I suppose you could create a gradient for the background?

Comment: I have tried not support for this '::selection' attribute. If you try please give me a sample.

Comment: Learn something about pseudo selectors like `:after` and `:before`.

Comment: Background gradient doesn't work.

Comment: you need to use js .... not possible purely with css

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank you for ruining at least an hour of my day, but I actually found a CSS-only solution. It's not really solid though, and it involves a lot of faking, but hey: No JavaScript!

We basically use a `data-content` attribute with the same content as the span holds, and then copy this to a layered `:after` element which displays it. We then hide the original text and apply a 50% height to the after element, this way the background color can only be applied to the bottom half.

```css
h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
}

h1:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

h1::selection {
    background: #fcf113;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="Hello world!">Hello world!</span>
```

Based on above, user @chrona made this really lovely working version:

```js
var paragraph = $('p');
var words     = paragraph.text().split(" ");

paragraph.empty();

$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    paragraph.append('<span data-word="' + v + '"> ' + v + ' </span>');
});
```

```css
p {
  background: white;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

span::after {
  background: white;
  content: attr(data-word);
  display: block;
  height: 75%;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 0.14em;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -0.28em;
  width: 100%;
}

span::selection {
  background: #fcf113;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: I guess to use this on a paragraph, you would have to wrap each word with a `<span data-content="word">` to make it work with line breaks? Anyway, nice solution!

Comment: Dirty but pretty cool. Maybe too much for a `::selection` effect but you definitely delivered!

Comment: @chrona You can escape <br>'s iirc, let me experiment a bit ;).

Comment: Oh @chrona this indeed will not work for them, because height: 50%. But close enough :(

Comment: It kind of works using `<span>`s on each word, but selecting 2 lines makes the color break pretty weird. https://jsfiddle.net/paLa4abL/

Comment: I'm including your jsfiddle in the answer as a snippet with credits, because it looks fantastic! @chrona

Comment: @Roberrrt  Thanks, It's really useful.

Comment: using `background` with `linear-gradient(transparent 30%, yellow 70%)` will do the trick. no need for this looooong work around.

Comment: @BiskremMuhammad You mean the same background that doesn't work on `::selection` yes?

Comment: @roberrrt-s Aw, no that was an assumption. based on doing that to highlight a `span`. but you're right `linear-gradient` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with gradients it work's fine.

```
<h1 class="grad">Design the Future Kitchen</h1>
```

Here's the css code.

```
.grad {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(255,255,0,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,0,1) 100%);
}
```

h1 must be an inline-element or do it with a span-tag.

```
h1 { 
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with css alone (without hacks), currently you can only style a small set of properties for `::selection` like `color`, `background-color`, `cursor`, `outline`, `text-decoration`, and `text-shadow`.

Other background properties will be ignored so using a gradient isn't possible.

---

If you really need the color as described you could use javascript to get the selected text, wrap it with a `<span>` and style that with CSS.

For small sentences or headlines, check out [Roberrrts CSS only answer](http://answer-41261374).

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-styling

Comment: Would be cool if there's an actual CSS way of fixing this though, let me check around.

Comment: Oh yes, it *is* possible using CSS alone! Posted my answer now. It's just really messy :).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do it with gradient effect:

```
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,0,0) 70%, rgba(255,255,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,0,0) 70%, rgba(255,255,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,0,0) 70%, rgba(255,255,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,0,0) 70%, rgba(255,255,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider the descenders of letters like `g` and `y`, you can modify the CSS code as follows:

```css
p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.half_bg {
  background: linear-gradient(/* Gradient from yellow to yellow */
  yellow, yellow)
  /* Starting position of the gradient */
  0
  /* Position of the gradient along the y-axis */
  70%
  /* Size of the gradient along the x-axis (full width) */
  / 100%
  /* Size of the gradient along the y-axis (1rem height) */
  1rem
  /* Background will not repeat */
  no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the <span class="half_bg">lazy dog</span>.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using box-shadow.

```css
h1 span{
  box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 0px 0px yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Here's Your Answer.</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.half-bg-effect {
  @apply inline text-black/90;
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70%,
    rgba(169, 213, 233, 0.5) 70%,
    rgba(180, 215, 233, 0.5) 100%
  );
}
```

I am using tailwind, just u need to set--> display:inline; and background i gave you for light blue, **NOTE**: u must need to use **[rgba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o64dE.jpg)** format, otherwise it will not work