# use css or js highlight text with half height

Tags: javascript, css, highlight

I need to do like the yellow line.
[image]

I know use `<span>` or `<p>` can imitate the mark effect.
But I need this mark **not to full** text height, must be 1/2 or 1/3 height.(like  picture)

I try to use pseudo class(before & after), but still failed.

Please give me some tips!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way I can think about is to use a `linear-gradient` to “half fill” your background:

```css
.half_background {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Some text, <span class="half_background">some other text with half background</span>.</p>
```

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

Then, we can easily expand that to do some other things:

```css
p {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
  padding: 0.6em;
}

.half_background {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, var(--bot) 50%, var(--top) 50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Some text, <span class="half_background" style="--top: transparent; --bot: yellow;">some other text with half background</span>.</p>
<p>Some text, <span class="half_background" style="--top: orange; --bot: transparent;">some other text with half background</span>.</p>
<p>Some text, <span class="half_background" style="--top: violet; --bot: cyan;">some other text with half background</span>.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```css
h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
}

h1:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

h1::selection {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="Hello world!">Hello world!</h1>
```

source:

[How to apply a background color to only half of the text on selecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260365/how-to-apply-a-background-color-to-only-half-of-the-text-on-selecting)

Answer (score 1):

I found* this and was so useful, I used it once.

```
.half-highlight {
  font-size: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, green 50%);
  background-origin: 0;
  background-size: 200% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
  background-position: -100% 100%;
}
```

Just use `<span class="half-highlight"> </span>` on the text you want to highlight, hope it works for you!!!

*source: https://codepen.io/JesmoDrazik/pen/ZWBdqq

Comment: This can be done easily with only 1 line of CSS, check my answer.

Comment: This method is also very useful when you need to make the text background have both a lower height and a gradient to the right/left

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use Linear Gradients in CSS3 to achieve this, but it's support for browsers is still on the edge. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Here's an example of how it will look:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <span class="highlighted">Sunt maiores, praesentium possimus itaque laudantium modi ratione cumque nisi quis quae hic. Maiores iure a dicta fugiat dolores modi in neque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span> Facere ipsum sequi necessitatibus ex consectetur libero cumque velit culpa aut quo magnam eaque adipisci cupiditate eos autem molestiae, quisquam vel iusto.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlighted {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

To check out the code in action, here's the link: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejBLeq?editors=1100